# cordova filereader blocks execution of javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm building cordova + angularjs application (with help of typescript and ng-cordova).
I have a problem with a cordova fileReader function which suppose to be async but in my case it blocks the execution of other javascript code including execution of ng-click directives.. While cordova reads a book index which is 10 mb in size all UI components do not respond.

```
loadIndexFromBookFolder(bookFolder: string): ng.IPromise<ft.ILoadIndex> {
    var currentClass: SearchService = this;
    var deferred = this.$q.defer<ft.ILoadIndex>();

    this.$cordovaFile.readFile(bookFolder + '/index').then(function (idx) {
        currentClass.$cordovaFile.readFile(bookFolder + '/idMap').then(function (idMap) {
              deferred.resolve({ index: lunr.Index.load(JSON.parse(idx)), idMap: JSON.parse(idMap) });
        }, failed);
    }, failed);

    var failed = (err) => {
        this.$log.debug('error: ' + err); 
        deferred.reject();
    };

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

If cordova filereader is async then what else could cause such problems with blocking java script?

Comment: What platform are you using? I could be that some platforms are sync while other are async.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using cordova and angular (Ionic 2) and maybe this can help you:

Try changing the loading order of *cordova.js* and *polyfill.js* scripts, in my case, loading the "polyfill.js" script before cordova script TOTALLY solved this problem.

Here is where I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283445/filereader-not-firing-onloadend-in-ionic-2), more info about this issue you can find [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/868).