# FileReader not firing onloadend in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm trying to read a local file using the cordova-file-plugin. At the moment I'm able to read the content of local directories and select a single file. But I have problems to get the content of the file.

Here's my function that's called by clicking a button after selecting a file from list:

```
import() {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.file.nativeURL, this.gotFile, this.fail);
}
```

And here're the two functions *gotFile* and *fail*:

```
fail(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

gotFile(fileEntry) {
    var file = fileEntry.nativeURL;

    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
             console.log('onloadend()'); 
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);

        console.log(reader);
    }); 
}
```

I can see in the log the *reader* with all the wanted content of my file under *result*, but I'm not able to get it and use it. The *readyState* is 2, but all inside reader.onloadend isn't called. With Ionic 1 this code works without any problems.

I would be very glad, if there's anyone how can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Known issue in ionic 2

Loading zone.js before cordova.js  fixes it.

Specific to ionic2 maintain this sequence order.

`<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script> <script src="cordova.js"</script>`

as the polyfills.js executes the zone.js.

Comment: I could fix the same issue. Thanks a lot. You saved me from 10 days of frustration.

Comment: My application was behaving weirdly: the number of colors declared in the theme was breaking parts of the software (database loading), after changing the sequence of imports, the software begun to work as expected.

Comment: @ParthGhiya where to add these lines in ionic?

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't used `onloadend`, I've been successfully using the `onload` event handler instead in Ionic 2, maybe you could give that one a try.

Keep in mind that it will return only if the operation is successful.